# How to use @if condition && condition in sass/scss

Tags: sass

i need to use this loop/condition :

```
@for $i from 1 to 6 {
    @if $i == 1 {
        /* ..... */           
    }@else if $i > 1 && $i < 6 {
        /* ..... */ 
    }@else if $i == 6{
        /* ..... */
    }
 }
```

But "&&" is not working in Sass/Scss ... any idea ?

then I tried this :

```
 @for $i from 1 to 6 {
    @if $i == 1 {
        /* ..... */           
    }@else if $i > 1 {
        /* ..... */ 
    }@else if $i > 5{
        /* ..... */
    }
 }
```

But last "@else if" is not working !!

Comment: "Not working" is not a very good description of the problem.  What isn't working?  Is the output wrong?  If it gives an error, what is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the keyword `and` in Sass instead of `&&` (and `or` instead of `||`):

```
@for $i from 1 to 6 {
    @if $i == 1 {
        /* ..... */           
    }@else if $i > 1 and $i < 6 {
        /* ..... */ 
    }@else if $i == 6{
        /* ..... */
    }
}
```

Though, your code would make more sense like this:

```
/* ..... */ // first          
@for $i from 2 through 5 {
    /* ..... */ 
 }
/* ..... */ // sixth
```

Note the difference between `X to Y` and `X through Y` in looping:  *through* includes Y, *to* excludes Y.

Answer (score 0):

it works :

```
 @for $i from 1 to 6 {
   @if $i == 1 {
       /* ..... */           
   }@else if $i < 5 {
       /* ..... */ 
   }@else {
       /* ..... */
   }
 }
```